# Max-speed in Z-Space

Tags: animorphs, transportation, z-space

It's obvious that Z-Space travel is faster than light, but how fast?  It's also obvious it isn't instantaneous, since they mention that there is boring travel times while in Z-Space.

Is there any mention of how fast a ship can travel between two points in Z-Space?

Comment: Taking relativity and modern physics into account, travelling at the speed of light pretty much means instantaneous.

Comment: *Hah! This is one of my favorite things when someone asks about the science. Because here's what you need to bear in mind: between us we have one BA in English and one GED. When it comes to science we are dumb and dumber. Ask jakemates. He can paint you a picture of just how technologically pathetic we are.* - [K.A. Applegate about speed of space travel in Animorphs](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/gzhau/iam_ka_applegate_author_of_animorphs_and_many/c1ri297)

Comment: @ibid That could be an answer.

Comment: @user867 - Saying that the authors didn't know physics doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @ibid Evidence that the authors *haven't* provided an answer to the question isn't a *satisfying* answer, but it is *an* answer, and a useful one; It lets people know that they're more likely to find an answer through rampant speculation than careful reading of the source material.

Comment: @user867 - She wasn't answering a question about z-space, I only referenced it because Rand mentioned science.

Comment: @ibid Oh, OK. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Randal'Thor What do you mean? What if the destination is 100 LY away?

Comment: @Fiksdal Not instantaneous in that sense. But according to special relativity, the speed of light is the fastest speed anything can travel, and travelling faster than that speed is sort-of equivalent to travelling backwards in time - which makes it function a bit like infinite speed (i.e. instantaneous travel).

Comment: @Randal'Thor  I don't know much about physics, so I'm unable to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you mean:

1. The actual speed through Z-space itself, unrelated to normal space.
2. The relative speed from point A to B in normal space. E.G. you spent a year travelling 100 LY in normal space distance, so your relative speed was 100 LY per year.

### Assuming #1

> As we spent timeless time traveling through the blank white **non-distance** of Zero-space...

<sup>The Andalite Chronicles, p. 70. Emphasis mine.</sup>

I'm not sure if it's even possible to measure speed in Z-space. What would you measure *against*? There is absolutely nothing there. It's just a great nothingness. Although in #18 The Decision, an Andalite ship (in an <s>Ellimist scheme</s> extremely unlikely coincidence) discovers and resuces the Animorphs while they are stuck in Z-space. So it does work a little bit like normal space where you can observe and interact with objects. This leads me to assume that spaceships can travel through Z-space with about the same speed they can travel through normal space with. There is no air or resistance in either, so I don't see why the speed would be different. How fast is this? On page 60 of *The Andalite Chronicles*, Elfangor, while in the vicinity of Saturn, explains that it would take "many days" to travel to Earth through normal space.

The distance from Saturn to Earth is (very) [roughly 1.5 billion kilometers](http://www.space.com/18477-how-far-away-is-saturn.html). (This also, very much depends on the orbits. It can vary between 1.2 and 1.7.) We can make a wild guess say that "many" days means something like ten days. That  means that they would have an average speed of **150 million kilometers per day**. This, of course, is an extremely rough guesstimate, but it can give you some idea of what ballpark we're talking about.

So, assuming that  Andalite spacecraft (or those of a similar level of technology) can travel about as fast in Z-space, we can assume **maybe somewhere between 100 million km per day and a few hundred million km per day.**

### Assuming #2

Z-space is constantly "reconfiguring" itself. There are many references to this throughout the series, for example:

> A Zero-space rift had opened up between planet Earth and the busy
>   centers of the galaxy. That happens sometimes. It meant that Earth,
>   rather than being days away, was now months and months away.

<sup>The Andalite Chronicles, p. 323.</sup>

So, relative to normal space, there is no fixed speed while traveling through Z-space. Even the Andalites can't predict how these rifts are going to occur. So a destination which is very far away one day, can be very close the next, and vice versa. This may mean that theoretically, **there is no maximum speed**. Maybe a reconfiguration one day could leave far corners of the galaxy a minute away from each other through a Z-space tunnel, resulting in a very high speed relative to normal space. While there may be a limit to what such reconfigurations can cause, I don't believe it has been described in canon.

In *The Andalite Chronicles*, Prince Alloran's ship travels from Earth's solar system to the Taxxon home world in what appears to be a very short time. He decides they are going there, announces it, has a pretty short conversation with his passengers, and suddenly they are there. No further waiting is described. This suggests that given a "lucky" configuration of Z-space, it's possible to travel incredibly fast. It would depend on the configuration or Z-space at the moment of travel. With the right configuration, it may be possible to travel across a galaxy in one minute. While that is a bit speculative, I'm not aware of any evidence that there's an actual limit to how fast these configurations can cause travel to be.